# How to change the opacity of an image using canvas and then loads it on another image in canvas?-HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I want to change the opacity of an image to make it transparent and loads that image over another image in canvas as I don't want to use any other tool to change opacity of first image. To change opacity of an image loaded in canvas

```
var imgObject=new Image();
imgObject.src="myImage.jpg";
// getting context of canvas
var ctx=document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
// global transparency applied on canvas context..
ctx.globalAlpha=0.5;
imgObject.onload=function(){
  ctx.drawImage(imgObject,0,0);
}
```

Is there any way to save transparent image (of canvas) and then use it to load it in new canvas on another image.

Comment: Can you share the fiddle ?

Comment: Please provide fiddle or image to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/krtmjzq6/

Comment: `drawImage` accepts a canvas as source, so you could just store your canvas in memory and reuse it later, or create a new one with `var saved = canvas.cloneNode(true);
saved.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0,0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to change opacity of image in HTML but you can change the opacity of context drawn on canvas element by setting **globalALpha**alALpha value:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx1 = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "img1.png";
// drawing first image on canvas..
img1.onload = function(){
   ctx1.drawImage(img1,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
};
var clonedCanvas = canvas.cloneNode(true);
var ctx2 = clonedCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img2 = new Image();
ctx2.globalAlpha = 0.4;
img2.src = "img2.jpg";
img2.onload = function(){
   ctx2.drawImage(img2,0,0);
// copying clonedCanvas to myCanvas.....
   ctx1.drawImage(clonedCanvas,0,0);
};
```